# Split comma(,) and caret (^) separated value in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to split a column string value to separate rows but so far no luck.

Here is my data set

```
990^275,987^280,988^278
```

I want to get the first value of each comma separated data set `i.e. 990,987,988 etc`. I have tried `substring_index` but not getting the result as I wanted. Here is what I have tried -

```
select  
  rooms_tariffs, 
  replace( rooms_tariffs,'^',','), 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(replace( rooms_tariffs,'^',','), ',', 1) "First",
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rooms_tariffs,'^',2),',', -1) "second"
from ewqhv_jomres_contracts 
order by 1 desc;
```

Output -

```
rooms_tariffs | rooms_tariffs | First | second
991^278,990^275 991,278,990,275 991 990
991^278,984^280 991,278,984,280 991 984
991^278 991,278 991 991^278
991^278 991,278 991 991^278
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty near, my friend. try this:

```
SELECT    `data`.`room_tariffs` AS `room_tariffs`,
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`.`room_tariffs`, ',', 1) AS `First`,
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`.`room_tariffs`, ',', -4), ',', 1) AS `Second`,
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`.`room_tariffs`, ',', -2), ',', 1) AS `Third`
FROM (
     SELECT    REPLACE(`room_tariffs`, '^', ',') AS `room_tariffs` 
     FROM      `ewqhv_jomres_contracts` 
     ORDER BY  1 desc;
     ) AS `data`
```

Output:

```
room_tariffs                First   Second  Third   
990,275,987,280,988,278     990     987     988
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works if I have 6 values but when I have two it still places the first value into second and third row

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have resolved it by creating a simple function below then calling it into my query script.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`( x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12),  pos INT) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1 RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),        LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
   delim, '');
```

I have called this function in my sql query like below -

```
 select room_no, split_str(room_no,',',1) "One", split_str(room_no,',',3) "Two", split_str( room_no,',',5) "Three" from room_view where tag=676648xx;
```